# incorporating p-value into box or violin plot

Tags: matplotlib, statistics, seaborn

I have made a violin plot with the code below (see pic for plot). I'm wondering if it's possible to get p-values of the differences between samples on the x axis. This could be any statistical test that shows a p-value, so if there is a global shift in the violin plot, the difference could be seen.

[violin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4cfK.png)

Edit:

For clarity, was hoping to add something like this to show pvals between samples:

```
for i,p in enumerate(pvals):
    if p>=0.05:
        displaystring = r'n.s.'
    elif p<0.0001:
        displaystring = r'***'
    elif p<0.001:
        displaystring = r'**'
    else:
        displaystring = r'*'
```

Python code for making violin plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Usage: Run script in ~/snakemake_eclip/scripts, use help function to see which parameters are needed.

This script takes in the all_reads_matrix made by merge_matrix.py and creates a violin plot.
"""

import pandas as pd
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
plt.switch_backend('agg')
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def make_violin(in_matrix, save_path):

    df = pd.read_csv(str(in_matrix), index_col=False)

    # remove outliers

    Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1

    df = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]

    # drop zeros

    df = df[(df != 0).all(1)]

    df = df.iloc[:, 1:].transform(lambda x: np.log(x / x.sum()))

    print(df)

    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=300)

    sns.violinplot(data=df)

    plt.plot()

    plt.title("Read Counts of Individual ENSG")
    plt.xlabel("Samples")
    plt.ylabel("Log Transformed Normalized Read Count")

    plt.savefig(os.path.join(str(save_path), 'all_reads_matrix_violin_plot_norm_log.pdf'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create a violin plot from all_reads_matrix.csv')

    parser.add_argument("--in_matrix",
                        help='name of input matrix')

    parser.add_argument("--save_path",
                        help='path to save')

    # parse out arguments

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # mutate matrix columns

    make_violin(args.in_matrix, args.save_path)
```

Comment: You can use `plt.text` to add p-values on top of the figure, or if you have one p-value per sample you could modify the xticklabels to contain your asterisks.

Comment: I need to find a way to automate the generation of these p values. There will be a new figure generated on each run of the program, so I can't manually add them with plt.text.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate p-values or how to plot the p-values once you generate them?

Comment: both in this case, I would think there is a function built into matplotlib that I could apply.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't do statistics; you'll need to calculate the p-values separately. Once you have them you can write them onto the plot using plt.text.